# Executing Stored Procedure With Dynamic Date Parameter - Conversion Error

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms, dateadd, sql-convert

I'm trying to execute the following stored procedure with a dynamic date parameter so that it picks up 6 months ago to yesterday.

When I run on a server with US language settings it works however when I run on a server with UK language settings I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I have tried converting the date to YYYYMMDD as this works on all servers however I have been unable to - I have even tried to force into a VARCHAR but no luck :(

Is there a way to get the date as YYYYMMDD format? Hope you can help.

```
USE Reports

DECLARE @DteStart   DATETIME2(3)
DECLARE @DteEnd     DATETIME2(3)
SELECT  @DteStart = DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),103))-6,0)
SELECT  @DteEnd   = DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),103))-1,0)
EXEC [dbo].[spReportsMyData] @DteStart, @DteEnd;
```

Comment: That code is product specific. Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: If you use the [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql) data type in all of the appropriate places there shouldn't be a problem. Fiddling with times you don't want and string representations is the way to madness. PSA: [ISO date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Comment: I can't reproduce it? What `language` are exactly using?

Comment: Its working now! I think our DBA's have been messing about with the language settings, all sorted, thanks for the responses :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Declare 
    @StartDate as Date
    , @EndDate as Date

Set @EndDate = DateAdd(Day, -1, Getdate())
Set @StartDate = DateAdd(Month, -6, @EndDate)

Select 
    Convert(VARCHAR(10), @StartDate, 112) As StartDate
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @EndDate, 112) As EndDate
```

Does your stored procedure seriously need the dates specifically in YYYYMMDD format, though?

Comment: As per comment above code is working now - thanks for the answer :)